# hourly cron messages re openssl cert usage error

Tags: ruby, ssl, cron, ssl-certificate, homebrew

A few days ago I was building a ruby app that had to use OpenSSL to access a web page.  It kept failing to connect to the web site https://regex.alf.nu, so I went to stackoverflow and after much research I concluded that my OpenSSL was out of date at version 0.9.8zc. I made the recommended changes (the details of which are provided below) and after that my app was able to read the text of the web site mentioned above.

Today I discovered that my system has been generating an error mail message almost every hour since I made these changes (beginning Sun Apr 12 08:00:01).  This is the text of the latest mail:

```
From SamShiffman@Samuels-MBP.PK5001Z  Thu Apr 16 12:00:01 2015
X-Original-To: SamShiffman
Delivered-To: SamShiffman@Samuels-MBP.PK5001Z
From: SamShiffman@Samuels-MBP.PK5001Z (Cron Daemon)
To: SamShiffman@Samuels-MBP.PK5001Z
Subject: Cron <SamShiffman@Samuels-MBP> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.4/bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=SamShiffman>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=SamShiffman>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/SamShiffman>
Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 12:00:01 -0700 (PDT)

Usage error; try -help.
rehash failed to verify, something is wrong
check /tmp/openssl-osx-ca.f9SEDVyI/cert.pem for problems
```

I haven't noticed any negative effects to my MBP, but I'm a little concerned that I may still have "broken" something the other day when I made those OpenSSL updates. As far as I can tell, the cron daemon error mails started after I ran these commands:

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
>Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Old.
>Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.

$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
> Updating certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Updating certificates in '/etc/openssl/cert.pem'.
> Updated.
> Updating certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already up to date.
```

After this I still couldn't connect to the aforementioned web site. After more research I found a post in stackoverflow that referred to a tool as a possible fix.  I ran:

```
$ brew tap raggi/ale
$ brew install openssl-osx-ca
>==> Installing openssl-osx-ca from raggi/homebrew-ale
>==> Downloading https://github.com/raggi/openssl-osx-ca/archive/1.0.4.tar.gz
>######################################################################## 100.0%
>==> make install PREFIX='/usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.4' BREW='/usr/loca
==> Caveats
>To uninstall remove the openssl-osx-ca line from your crontab. e.g.

>    (crontab -l | grep -v openssl-osx-ca) | crontab -
>==> Summary
>  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.4: 4 files, 16K, built in 2 seconds

$ git clone https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools.git

$ brew link openssl --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1... 1543 symlinks created

$ brew install curl-ca-bundle
Error: No available formula for curl-ca-bundle 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...

$ ruby ssl-tools/doctor.rb
/Users/SamShiffman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby (2.0.0-p598)
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015: /usr/local/etc/openssl
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE=""

HEAD https://status.github.com:443
/Users/SamShiffman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:175:in `sysread_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)

$ ruby ssl-tools/doctor.rb 'regex.alf.nu'
/Users/SamShiffman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby (2.0.0-p598)
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015: /usr/local/etc/openssl
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE=""

HEAD https://regex.alf.nu:443
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:
  subject: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.alf.nu
  issuer: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
  error code 20: unable to get local issuer certificate

Possible causes:
  `/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/' is empty

$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/SamShiffman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p598'.
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
```

After all this I still couldn't get the app to connect to the web site. I finally added this to my code (from a stackoverflow post) and it worked:

```
 def get_html_string(url = @url)
    uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    # http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)
    response.body
  end
```

Now it seems all the other steps I took leading up to this were unnecessary, but I don't know.  At this point in the absence of any advice I would remove the openssl-osx-ca line from my crontab using:

```
(crontab -l | grep -v openssl-osx-ca) | crontab -
```

...but I'd like some confirmation from some code veterans who know more about this than I do.

Thank you

### UPDATE 17Apr 11:00PDT

I upgraded brew, reinstalled openssl and recreated symlinks:

```
$ brew update
$ brew doctor

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    openssl
$ brew reinstall openssl
$ brew link openssl --force

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1... 1543 symlinks created

$ brew upgrade
```

and the cron daemon mails stopped! Been rockin' 'n rollin' ever since.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded brew, reinstalled openssl and recreated symlinks:

```
$ brew update
$ brew doctor
Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    openssl

$ brew reinstall openssl
$ brew link openssl --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2a-1... 1543 symlinks created

$ brew upgrade
```

and the cron daemon mails stopped! Been rockin' 'n rollin' ever since.